# Perl one-liner: deleting a line with pattern matching

Tags: perl

I am trying to delete bunch of lines in a file if they match with a particular pattern  which is variable.

I am trying to delete a line which matches with abc12, abc13, etc.

I tried writing a C-shell script, and this is the code:

```
    **!/bin/csh
    foreach $x (12 13 14 15 16 17)
    perl -ni -e 'print unless /abc$x/' filename
    end**
```

This doesn't work, but when I use the one-liner without a variable (abc12), it works.

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the pattern matching or if there is something else I am missing.

Comment: `perl -i -ne '/abc1[234567]/ or print' filename`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's the fact you're using single quotes. It means that `$x` is being interpreted literally.

Of course, you're *also* doing it very inefficiently, because you're processing each file multiple times.

If you're looking to remove lines `abc12` to `abc17` you can do this all in one go:

```
perl -n -i.bak -e 'print unless m/abc1[234567]/' filename
```

Comment: Ideally if you have an answer that meets your needs, you should accept it. (that little tick by the side)

Comment: Sorry ,I didn't know that ,I am new here  ,thanks for the tip.

Comment: How can I delete the next line of this match?

Comment: With a different approach I'm afraid. It'd be worth asking that as a separate question. The above only works line by line.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
perl -n -i.bak -e 'print unless m/abc1[2-7]/' filename
```

using the range [2-7] only removes the need to type [234567] which has the effect of saving you three keystrokes.

man 1 bash: **Pattern Matching**

**[...]** Matches any one of the enclosed characters. A pair of characters separated by a *hyphen* denotes a range expression; any character that sorts between those two characters, inclusive, using the current locale's collating sequence and character set, is matched. If the first character following the **[** is a **!** or a **^** then any character not enclosed is matched.

A **-** may be matched by including it as the first or last character in the set. A **]** may be matched by including it as the first character in the set.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.